# .htaccess - Heal malformed url

Tags: .htaccess, url, parameters, malformed

I need a solution. For some reason in the past seems that I generate some "bad" links for bots only.

Resume: There is a fake "page" parameter when malformed url is present. When there are 2 "page" parameters then the first one is fake, must be removed.

1. X is random
2. Remove the parameter page only when "**?/?page**" is detected

Good: **search?pagepage=496**

Bad:  **search?/?page=X**

Good: https://example.com/search?page=496

Good: https://example.com/search?page=496&orderBy=oldest

Bad: https://example.com/search?/?page=X&page=496&orderBy=oldest

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?^XXX[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule...
```

Thank you guys!

**UPDATE**

At final, I found a solution by myself:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?^/\?page=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /search$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Try `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/\?page=.+&(page=.*)`, followed by `RewriteRule ^(search)$ $1?%1 [R=302]` (302 for testing, make it 301 later when it all works as it should.)

Comment: Please check the answer I just posted, I think that should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/\?page=.+&(page=.*)
RewriteRule ^(search)$ $1?%1 [R=301]
```

This will do the rewrite for all your URLs that have the extra `page` parameter you want to keep.

To make the last part optional, we would have to wrap `&(page=.*)` into another set of braces, and add a `?` as quantifier - `(&(page=.*))?`.
Then the back reference would need to be changed from `%1` to `%2` (because we only need that inner part, we don't want the `&`) - but then for your URL without any real `page` parameter to keep, there would be no match in this place, and therefor the `%2` would not be substituted with anything, but added to the URL *literally*.

So better to leave the above as-is, and simply add

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/\?page=.+
RewriteRule ^(search)$ $1 [QSD,R=301]
```

below those two existing lines. The pattern does not need to be any more specific (because the URLs that have a genuine `page` parameter at the end, have already been handled by those previous two lines.) And the `QSD` makes it simply drop the existing query string, so that `https://example.com/search?/?page=20` results in `https://example.com/search` (which I assume is what you wanted here, because there is no actual page parameter to keep, correct?)

Comment: one more thing. In case of languages, I have 20. In this example is the "/en/". When the language is present, seems that the solution doesn't work, cand you do something please? Thank you! Example: https://example.com/en/search?/?page=18&orderBy=oldest&page=5

Comment: You need to make the RewriteRule pattern match that as well then, something like `RewriteRule ^(((en|fr)/)?(search))$ $1?%1 [R=301]` Or use a character class, if you don't want to write them down all as alternatives, `[a-z]{2}` or something.